# WooCommerce product - Displaying post_content value of product object

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, product

When I use:

```
print_r($product);
```

It returns the following:

```
WC_Product_Simple 
Object 
    ( [id] => 156 
      [post] => WP_Post Object 
           ( [ID] => 156 
             [post_author] => 1 
             [post_date] => 2016-07-01 08:59:05 
             [post_date_gmt] => 2016-07-01 06:59:05 
             [post_content] => single product with picture

             .....
```

How do I echo out the value for **`[post_content]`**?

I am using WordPress with WooCommerce plugin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see your **`$product`** is an object that contains a **`post`** object (and not arrays). So you could try one of this:

```
$product_content = $product->post->post_content;
echo $product_content;
// or directly
// echo $product->post->post_content;
```

or this one should work too:

```
$_product = $product->post;
echo $_product->post_content;
```

Comment: done :) i am now reading up on objects, used to do php 6 years ago and im pretty sure i never used an object before